# Preventing sending e-mail to user if he didn't filled the e-mail field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I have a Rails application, where I have a visitors_controller for homepage and a contacts_controller for contact form. My website has to be single-paged, so I'm invoking Contact.new inside visitors controller.

When the submit action is executed, in contacts_controller the user is redirected to `root_path`, in save or in error.

There is an email field which is used to deliver the user a mail. The setback happens when the user doesn't fill it and for some reason the user is redirected to contacts_path instead of root_path.

It throws the following error: `An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address.`

This is the function that reads the email and delivers to the user:  `VisitorMailer.landing_form_notify_user(@contact).deliver_now`
Not filling it redirects the user to contacts_index.

**Question: How can I stop executing this function if the user hasn't filled the email field?**

> app/controllers/visitors_controller.rb

```
class VisitorsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @contact = Contact.new
  end
end
```

> app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb

```
 def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.save
        VisitorMailer.landing_form_notify_user(@contact).deliver_now
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Good' }
        format.json { render root_path, status: :created, location: @contact }
      else
        format.html { render root_path }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

> app/mailers/visitors_mailer.rb

```
  class VisitorMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default :from => "mygmail@gmail.com"

    def landing_form_notify_user(user)
         @user = user
         email_with_name = %("#{@user.name}" <#{@user.email}>)
         mail(
           to: "#{@user.email}",
           subject: "#{@user.name}" + ', hi.'
         )
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to attempt to send an email if the email address is missing, all you have to do is check for an email address before you call the mailer.

```
 def create
   @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

   respond_to do |format|
     if @contact.save
       unless @contact.email.blank?
         VisitorMailer.landing_form_notify_user(@contact).deliver_now
       end
       # more stuff to do if save succeeds
     else
       # stuff to do if save fails
     end
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

`VisitorMailer.landing_form_notify_user(@contact).deliver_now if @contact.email.present?`